# Blender big scaled fluid simulation problem

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm in trouble with blender fluid simulation (which is very awesome!) because i want to create a big scaled water simulation with a ship leaving the water. But it's a very big ship (700m length) and i did everything i could but the water stills too big. I found nothing on the subject except fantastic animations but no tutorials.

I tried hight resolutions like 64 to 320 but the result stills the same. Also i reduced particles radius, the amount per cell (increase to 32 instead of 16), increased the mesh upres, particles upresh too to 3-5.

[image]

As you can see on the picture it's what i'm triyng to do. The ship flys to the sky with large and smal water spray and foam, but i only geta water mesh too big to be realistic.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Are you talking about Fluid simulation, or Ocean simulation?

Comment: It's only fluid. I tried hight resolution but that chnaged nothing.

Comment: You might want to look into an add-on called "Flip-Fluids". It's an advanced fluid simulator which might suit your needs. I watched a video on a "water surface breach" in blender, and the creator said in addition to Flip Fluids, they used an ocean modifier for the surface of the water, and then used a displace modifier to transfer the motion to the fluid sim. Video is here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkSwqWZt2aI

Comment: I'm actually here for the same issue with Flip Fluids lol...seems its not very scalable to large areas, I was trying to model waves along a coastline of several km long and it's just not happening

Comment: I see. I have the same conclusions. But i'll just keep this open just in case. Thanks!